# Can I make a function generic implicitly?

Tags: typescript

I have this function:

```
export function randomChoice(arr: readonly any[]) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
```

That I use like so:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const b = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
console.log(randomChoice(a));
console.log(randomChoice(b));
```

However, I'd like the return value to be typed, i.e.

```
//This should show an error, as length does not exist on number
console.log(randomChoice(a).length);
//This should not show an error:
console.log(randomChoice(b).length);
//Currently, neither show errors, as the return type is any
```

I know I could get `randomChoice` to show typing desired errors as I'd like using a generic:

```
export function randomChoice<T>(arr: readonly T[]) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
//Typing error here
console.log(randomChoice<number>(a)!.length);
//No typing error here
console.log(randomChoice<string>(b)!.length);
```

But since I mostly call `randomChoice` with constants, I'd love a way to skip having to explicitly state the generic type. Can I rewrite `randomChoice` so the return type is typed based on the input?

Comment: Just remove `<number>`  and `<string>`.

Comment: Ah dammit, @hoangdv you genius.

Comment: Man maybe I should delete this question

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @hoangdv , which I should have tried; it just works implicitly already.

```
export function randomChoice<T>(arr: readonly T[]) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
//As desired,
//Typing error here
console.log(randomChoice(a)!.length);
//No typing error here
console.log(randomChoice(b)!.length);
```